# What affiliation should I use for a paper that I partly wrote in a previous institution?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate, independent-researcher

I am writing a research paper to be submitted to an IEEE conference. Part of the work was performed as a part of my University. I have graduated from there and am no longer a part of the university. My work has evolved and I would like to publish these results. What should my affiliation be for this paper? Should I use my old university as my affiliation or using something like IEEE-RAS member is fine?

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, you would need to somehow indicate both but a similar question has been asked and answered before:

[What affiliation to put on an academic paper for alumni authors?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11841/what-affiliation-to-put-on-an-academic-paper-for-alumni-authors)

You have to acknowledge that part of the work was performed when you were at your university. I had a similar situation where I did part of the work when I was at university as part of my PhD and then completed the work when I took up a position at a research institution. For the paper, I was listed as having two affiliations.

Comment: Yes, I will acknowledge the work done to my university. Since I am a independent researcher now, what will my current affiliation be? I am thinking to use, IEEE RAS member as the primary affiliation, and acknowledge my university in the footnote. Is that okay?

Comment: I suppose that would be ok, but are you still in contact with your supervisor from the university by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am still in contact with the supervisor. Actually, a preliminary paper based on the same work was accepted in a conference, I had put his name as the co-author. Since now he did not participate much for the further work, I am considering not to include his name

Comment: If you are using work that he supervised actively, I feel that you should include his name. For example, in papers in my field (I am an experimental physicist), we include the names of everyone who helped to acquire the data, even if they were not involved in the analysis and write up of the paper. I also think that you could ask your previous supervisor his opinion on your affiliation. He will be familiar with the university expectations and intellectual property aspects.

Comment: If that's the case, I will talk to my supervisor. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

It is the institution where the work was primarily conducted. You can add a note/comment that ‘author x is now at y’ but officially it would be the former in most cases